# Why can't I apply pattern-matching against non-case classes?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is there a better explanation than "this is how it works". I mean I tried this one:

```
class TestShortMatch[T <: AnyRef] {
  def foo(t: T): Unit = {
    val f = (_: Any) match {
      case Val(t) => println(t)
      case Sup(l) => println(l)
    }
  }

  class Val(t: T)
  class Sup(l: Number)
}
```

and compiler complaints:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'Val'`
`Cannot resolve symbol 'Sup'`

Of course if I add `case` before each of the classes it will work fine. But what is the reason? Does compiler make some optimization and generate a specific byte-code?

Comment: The canonical reference is chapter 24 of Programming in Scala. The book is in its 3rd edition so the 1st ed is online http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html

Answer (score 6):

The reason is twofold. Pattern matching is just syntactic sugar for using [extractors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) and [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) happen to give you a couple methods for free, one of which is an extractor method that corresponds to the main constructor.

---

If you want your example above to work, you need to define an `unapply` method inside objects `Val` and `Sup`. To do that you'd need extractor methods (which are only defined on `val` fields, so you'll have to make your fields `val`s):

```
class Val[T](val t: T)
class Sup(val l: Number)

object Val {
   def unapply[T](v: Val[T]): Option[T] = Some(v.t)
}
object Sup {
   def unapply(s: Sup): Option[Number] = Some(s.l)
}
```

And which point you can do something like `val Val(v) = new Val("hi")`. More often than not, though, it is better to make your class a `case` class. Then, the only times you should be defining extra extractors.

The usual example (to which I can't seem to find a reference) is coordinates:

```
case class Coordinate(x: Double, val: Double)
```

And then you can define a custom extractors like

```
object Polar {
  def unapply(c: Coordinate): Option[(Double,Double)] = {...}
}
object Cartesian {
  def unapply(c: Coordinate): Option[(Double,Double)] = Some((c.x,c.y))
}
```

to convert to the two different representations, all when you pattern match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching on arbitrary classes, but you need to implement [an unapply method](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html), used to "de-construct" the object.

With a case class, the unapply method is automatically generated by the compiler, so you don't need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `match exp { case Val(pattern) => ... case ... }`, that is equivalent to something like this:

```
match Val.unapply(exp) {
  case Some(pattern) =>
    ...
  case _ =>
    // code to match the other cases goes here
}
```

That is, it uses the result of the companion object's `unapply` method to see whether the match succeeded.

If you define a case class, it automatically defines a companion object with a suitable `unapply` method. For a normal class it doesn't. The motivation for that is the same as for the other things that gets automatically defined for case classes (like `equals` and `hashCode` for example): By declaring a class as a case class, you're making a statement about how you want the class to behave. Given that, there's a good chance that the auto generated will do what you want. For a general class, it's up to you to define these methods like you want them to behave.

Note that parameters for case classes are `val`s by default, which isn't true for normal classes. So your class `class Val(t: T)` doesn't even have any way to access `t` from the outside. So it isn't even possible to define an `unapply` method that gets at the value of `t`. That's another reason why you don't get an automatically generated `unapply` for normal classes: It isn't even possible to generate one unless all parameters are `val`s.